# Property 'selectedCharacter' does not exist on type 'Store'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am not sure why I am getting this error

Property 'selectedCharacter' does not exist on type 'Store'.ts(2339)

when all I am trying to do is a call a function from the Character store.

characterDetails.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useStore } from "../../../app/store/store";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";


export default function CharacterDetails() {
  const characterStore = useStore();
  const {id} = useParams();
  

  useEffect(() => {
    characterStore.selectedCharacter();
  })

  return (
    <h1>{character.name}</h1>
  );
}
```

CharacterStore.ts

```
import { makeAutoObservable, runInAction } from "mobx";
import agent from "../api/agent";
import { Character } from "../models/character"
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';

export default class CharacterStore {
    characters: Character[] = [];
    selectedCharacter: Character | undefined = undefined;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }
  
  loadCharacters = async() => {
    try {
      const characters = await agent.Characters.list();
      console.log(characters);
        characters.forEach(character => {
          this.characters.push(character);
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  selectCharacter = (id: string) => {
    this.selectedCharacter = this.characters.find(a => a.id === id);
  }

  createCharacter = async (character: Character) => {
    character.id = uuid();
    try {
      await agent.Characters.create(character);
      runInAction(() => {
        this.characters.push(character);
        this.selectedCharacter = character;
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this error. Any help would be very appreciated.

I would like to be able to be able to display a single character profile when the function is called.

Comment: Can you share the `useStore` function? It could be `const { characterStore } = useStore();`

Comment: ````
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import CharacterStore from './characterStore'

interface Store{
    characterStore: CharacterStore
}

export const store: Store = {
    characterStore: new CharacterStore()
}

export const StoreContext = createContext(store);

export function useStore() {
    return useContext(StoreContext)
}
````

Comment: Yeah, try as I suggested above.

Comment: wow I feel silly. Thanks that worked